# How to check pin outs for FBT

Tags: flyback, testing

I bought a flyback transformer recently, 5908-05008, CF68A. However, when I try searching online for this model, there seems to be no pin out diagram or any information at all. Most of the FBT I saw had either 10 pins or 13 pins while this flyback has 9 pins.

I understand that there is 2 potentiometer for tuning Focus and Screen but other than that, I have no idea how to test it for it's winding, turn ratio, inductance value and KVA.

I was wondering if there is anyway to test and find out which pins are for what purpose and how to check the parameters for this flyback. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: So why did you buy it if there's no data sheet or information about it available? You can likely use an ohmmeter to figure out the winding configuration, and a scope, current probe and voltage source to plot out the saturation characteristic but I would just go buy another transformer that actually has a data sheet.

Comment: @JohnD Well, I went into several shops looking for a flyback and only 1 sells it. However, they had no idea on the specifications  but said that students were using it for their project and I figure that I might get some info from the web...so I bought it. Correct me if I'm wrong, do I supply a voltage of maybe..24V through one of the pins in the suction cup and using the voltmeter , one probe to the ground of the power supply and one probe to each pin? Will that give me the hint of which pin might be the secondary input? However,is there a risk of it overheating and burning down the place?

Comment: @Miau Most likely that method will not work because many of the pins might be taps on the secondary winding, rather than separate winding terminals. Your best bet is to apply a drive signal to the two pins on the top right of the image in the top right. Those look most to me like the primary winding terminals. If you connect an ohmmeter across them it should be relatively low (within 10 ohms, I would expect, probably quite a bit less). Once the drive signal is turned on, hold the suction cup to the remaining pins and see which one it arcs to the most. That will be your GND

Comment: If you don't get an arc at all, try swapping the drive input wires. The output is rectified, so you will not really get anything on the output if the input polarity is backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifying FBT leads is not easy but it is not impossible. What you need is a dc24V power supply and a 1K ohm resistor. Connect the resistor on the positive terminal of the power supply. Draw two test probes, one from the negative terminal of the power supply and another test probe (positive) from the resistor.

Connect the volts meter across the resistor. This setup is actually a high compliance ammeter capable of forward biasing high voltage rectifiers.

Firstly to identify the EHT secondary winding, link the negative test probe to the EHT suction cup and cycle the positive probe thru each pins of the FBT. When the positive probe finds the end of the EHT winding, current shall flow thus indicates voltage readings in the volt meter. At this moment probe polarity can be reversed to verify the integrity of the rectifier diode.

The other pins of the transformer can be identified similarly. The primary usually have the highest resistance and it may have other tappings as well. High resistance will cause lower current flow thus exhibit lower voltage readings across the resistor.

Resistance is the function of the wire length and wire diameter. It is merely used to understand how the connections are made. Once all connections are figured out and understood, another test can be performed to understand the turns ratio.

FBT operates at around 16KHz. A low voltage DC source such as 12V chopped at 16KHz can be injected in one of the isolated winding and voltage measurements can be taken across all windings identified in previous step. Some windings will produce higher voltages compared to another. Mark them accordingly and by now the turns ratios should be apparent.

During this step BEWARE of the high voltage at the EHT suction cup..!! It can easily go beyond few kilovolts.

Comment: I have a dc supply of 24v with 2A flowing through and a 1/2W 1kohm resistor, do i have to find some other resistor?

Comment: That resistor is good enough to be used in the procedure I described above.

Comment: I tried using the connection you suggested, however, I think I might have blown the circuit breaker throughout the office. help?

Comment: Ist??  I adviced you to use low voltage, what voltage you used?

Comment: @steven soosai Hm, I used a 24V/2A DC PSU and I set it up like this. Might look a little messy but the blue is the positive and white is the negative. Does the connection from the EHT cup matters as there are 2 output wires?http://i.stack.imgur.com/ICF4V.jpg

Comment: Your connections looks fine. Only thing wrong is the polarity of the multimeter probes. No way this caused black out in yr office. Whatsapo me at +60125822504